# How to add a date in listview column header automatically

Tags: listview, vb6

I have month and listview control in the form

If i select the month, the listview display the date in the column header.

For Example

If i select the `Month 02/2009`

Then ListView Should display Like this

```
01, 02, 03 .... 31 (List View Column Header)
```

How to do this?

Comment: You should show us what you have tried so far, post some code as we are here to help with problems, not to provide complete solutions. Feel free to read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of days in the month for a given date using a combination of `DateDiff()` and `DateAdd()`.

```
Days = Datediff("d",  YourDate, DateAdd("m", 1, YourDate))
```

This works out the difference in days between your data and the date 1 month on.

This value can then be used in a standard `For`/`Next` loop to add columns to your list control.